# Adding a username property to webapp2 User model after entity has been created (with Simpleauth)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, app-engine-ndb

I'm currently using Python / App Engine / SimpleAuth to provide OAuth login to my application. The current workflow is that users login with OAuth, and they can later create a unique username for themselves in the app.

I'm having problems creating the unique username after the webapp2 User entity has already been created.  I see that in the [webapp2 model](https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.py) there is a way to enable a unique username within the application Entity group, but I don't know how to set it for myself.  (I'm using [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) to set everything for other OAuth providers.)

I want to check to see if the user-submitted 'username' exists, and if it doesn't to add it as a property to the currently logged-in user.  I'd appreciate any help/pointers on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could extend `webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User` and add username property, e.g.

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User as Webapp2User

class User(Webapp2User):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Then, to create a webapp2 app you'd need a config which includes this:

```
APP_CFG = {
  'webapp2_extras.auth': {
    'user_model': User,  # default is webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User
    'user_attributes': ['username']  # list of User model properties
  }
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(config=APP_CFG)
```

Havign the above, creating a new user using the following code will ensure username is unique (ensured by Unique model):

```
auth_id = 'some-auth-id'  # e.g. 'google:123456789', see simpleauth example.
ok, props = User.create_user(auth_id, unique_properties=['username'],
                                      username='some-username',
                                      ...)
if not ok:
  # props list will contain 'username', indicating that
  # another entity with the same username already exists
  ...
```

Problem is, with this configuration you are bound to set `username` during the creation time.

If you wanted to make username optional, or let users set/change it later on, you would probably want to change the above code to something like this:

```
class User(Webapp2User):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()  # note, there's no required=True

# when creating a new user:
auth_id = 'some-auth-id'  # e.g. 'google:123456789', see simpleauth example.
ok, props = User.create_user(auth_id, unique_properties=[], ...)
```

Basically, `unique_properties` will be empty list (or you can just skip it). Also, you could temporarily assign `username` property to something like `user.key.id()` until the user decides to change their username to something more meaningful. Take, for instance, Google+ profile links: mine is currently https://plus.google.com/114517983826182834234, but if they let me change it, I would try something like https://plus.google.com/+IamNotANumberAnymore

Then, in a "change/set username" form handler, you could check if a username already exists and update User entity (if it doesn't):

```
def handle_change_username(self):
  user = ...  # get the user who wants to change their username
  username = self.request.get('username')
  uniq = 'User.username:%s' % username
  ok = User.unique_model.create(uniq)
  if ok:
    user.username = username
    user.put()
  else:
    # notify them that this username
    # is already taken
    ...
```

`User.unique_model.create(uniq)` will create a `Unique` entity with the given value if it didn't exist. In this case `ok` will be `True`. Otherwise, `ok` will be `False` which indicates that an entity with that value (a unique username in this case) already exists.

Also, you might want to put `User.unique_model.create()` and `user.put()` in the same transaction (it'll be XG because they are in different entity groups).

Hope this helps!